# Django error when trying to display the sign up form

Tags: python, django

So I have this form which extends the User and I just want to allow the student to create and account and be able to select the courses from the course list.But when I try, I get the error:

```html
__init__() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given
```

I can't find any solution to this yet. I need some advice.
These are my files:

```js
{% block body %}
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-8 col-sm-10 col-12">
      <h2>Sign up as a {{ user_type }}</h2>
      <form method="post" novalidate>
        {% csrf_token %}
        <input type="hidden" name="next" value="{{ next }}">
        {{ form }}
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Sign up</button>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
{% endblock %}
```

```css
class User(AbstractUser):
    is_student = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_teacher = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

```html
path('signup/', views.StudentSignUpView, name='signup')


class StudentSignUpForm(UserCreationForm):
    attended_courses = forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField(
        queryset=Course.objects.all(),
        widget=forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple,
        required=True
    )

    class Meta(UserCreationForm.Meta):
        model = User

    @transaction.atomic
    def save(self):
        user = super().save(commit=False)
        user.is_student = True
        user.save()
        student = Student.objects.create(user=user)
        student.attended_courses.add(*self.cleaned_data.get('attended_courses'))
        return user
```

```html
class StudentSignUpView(CreateView):
    model = User
    form_class = StudentSignUpForm
    template_name = 'signup_form.html'

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        kwargs['user_type'] = 'student'
        return super().get_context_data(**kwargs)

    def form_valid(self, form):
        user = form.save()
        login(self.request, user)
        return redirect('index')
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Class-based views need to be referenced in urls.py via their `as_view` method.

```
path('signup/', views.StudentSignUpView.as_view(), name='signup')
```

Comment: Yes, totally forgot. Thanks!